# Estimate number of n-node paths in graph using only n and graph density

Tags: graph, graph-theory

I have a large, dense graph (~33,000 nodes, ~345 million edges, so the graph density is approximately 0.63). I'm interested in estimating the number of 3-edge paths in this graph. Is there an accurate estimation using only this information (ie no adjacency matrices)?

Comment: Similar question was asked on [cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20246/counting-the-number-of-simple-paths-in-undirected-graph) - take a look if the answers there can be adapted to your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a rough estimate is good enough (and the number k of edges in the paths is fix and small): let d be the density, then you have n starting nodes, about n * d possible second nodes, ... and about n * d^k end nodes. If k is small the number of paths with cycles are small opposed to the simple paths. The number of all paths would be about n^(k+1) * d^(k(k+1)/2) - so this would be a (quite) rough estimate.